# Shell Script - Merging all rows in file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep, sh

Please suggest how to achieve below output. 
Like to merge row in Shell scripting.

Tried few things but no success. Kindly check the below screenshot for the same. 
[image]

I attempted the following:

```
cat RAWDATA.csv | sed '1d'| sort | awk -F',' '{if(a!=$1) {a=$1; printf "\n%s%s",$0,FS} else {a=$1;$1="";printf $0 }} END {printf "\n" }'
```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: What are the few things you've tried so far ?

Comment: Tried: 
 cat RAWDATA.csv | sed '1d'| sort | awk -F',' '{if(a!=$1) {a=$1; printf "\n%s%s",$0,FS} else {a=$1;$1="";printf $0 }} END {printf "\n" }'

Comment: In which shell ? sh or bash or ksh ? (I see there is the sh flag, but just making sure.

Comment: Please post text instead of images so that it can be used for testing scripts.

Comment: Please post example input and expected output as text.

Comment: Andre... it is bash

Comment: Could you please post your original files. You mention CSV, but a lot of people mention the term CSV file while it is actually a normal file, or anything except CSV.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work, obviously not tested since there is no testable input file.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
       NR==1 {print; next}
             {ks[k]; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i!="N") a[k,i]=$i}
         END {for(k in ks) {
                printf "%s", k
                for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", OFS (a[k,i]?a[k,i]:"N");
                print ""}' file
```